# mdfind and the apostrophe

Tags: command-line, spotlight, search

In terminal if I type

```
mdfind -onlyin ~/"Desktop/Shows I Watch" "Bob"
```

I get the output

> /Users/brendans/Desktop/Shows I Watch/Bob's Burgers

As I would expect. But if I try

```
mdfind -onlyin ~/"Desktop/Shows I Watch" "Bob's Burgers"
```

I get nothing. I've tried lots of different escape keys for the apostrophe, but they all return nothing.

Here's a list of everything I've tried:

```
mdfind -onlyin ~/"Desktop/Shows I Watch" "Bob\'s Burgers"
mdfind -onlyin ~/"Desktop/Shows I Watch" "Bob\''s Burgers"
mdfind -onlyin ~/"Desktop/Shows I Watch" "Bob''s Burgers"
mdfind -onlyin ~/"Desktop/Shows I Watch" "Bob\\'s Burgers"
mdfind -onlyin ~/"Desktop/Shows I Watch" "'Bob'\\''s Burgers'"
```

What am I missing here?!?

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the single apostrophe with a single backslash and do not quote the show name if it has an apostrophe, just escape any spaces with a single backslash too, as in the examples below:

```
$ mdfind -onlyin ~/Desktop/"Shows I Watch" Bob\'s\ Burgers
/Users/name/Desktop/Shows I Watch/Bob's Burgers
$ mdfind -onlyin ~/Desktop/Shows\ I\ Watch Bob\'s\ Burgers
/Users/name/Desktop/Shows I Watch/Bob's Burgers
$
```

It should actually work with the show name in quotes as in the first example you have under "Here's a list of everything I've tried:", it worked on my system.

```
$ mdfind -onlyin ~/"Desktop/Shows I Watch" "Bob\'s Burgers"
/Users/name/Desktop/Shows I Watch/Bob's Burgers
$
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
mdfind -onlyin ~/Desktop/"Shows I Watch" Bob\'s\ Burgers 
works as expected.